# Looking For a Correct Way to Hide or Display Streets on Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to Hide/ Display Roads layers on Google Map at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/60d3dn7f/1/) which is working for me but as you can see the code is duplicated in adding style many times!
on:

```
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    map.set('styles', [{
        "featureType": "road",
            "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    }]);

    $('input:checkbox').change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            map.set('styles', [{
                "featureType": "road",
                    "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "on"
                }]
            }]);
        } else {
            map.set('styles', [{
                "featureType": "road",
                    "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }]);
        }
    });
```

can you please take a look at demo and let me what is a better way to achieve this? without repeating the style many times?!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hold the styles in a variable for example:

```
var stylesOff = [{
    "featureType": "road",
        "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
    }]
}];

var stylesOn = [{
    "featureType": "road",
        "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "on"
    }]
}];

var myOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: latlng,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    styles: stylesOff
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

$('input:checkbox').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        map.setOptions({
            styles: stylesOn
        });
    } else {
        map.setOptions({
            styles: stylesOff
        });
    }
});
```

Mind the use of `setOptions` which is the documented method to change map options.

**Edit:**

As you said in your comment that you want to toggle multiple styles independently, here is a solution.

It uses the inputs `data` attributes to identify which style the checkbox refers to.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="styles-control" data-style="road" checked="checked"> Roads
<input type="checkbox" class="styles-control" data-style="poi" checked="checked"> POI
<input type="checkbox" class="styles-control" data-style="administrative.locality" checked="checked"> Localities
<input type="checkbox" class="styles-control" data-style="water" checked="checked"> Water
```

Based on that, you can build your array of styles when one of the checkbox changes:

```
// Get all styles controls
var controls = $('.styles-control');

$('.styles-control').change(function () {

    styles = [];

    // Loop through styles controls
    for (var i = 0; i < controls.length; i++) {

        if ($(controls[i]).is(':checked')) {

            // Push the feature type to the styles array
            // The feature type is based on the input data-style attribute
            styles.push({
                "featureType": $(controls[i]).data('style'),
                    "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "on"
                }]
            });
        } else {
            styles.push({
                "featureType": $(controls[i]).data('style'),
                    "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            });
        }
    }

    map.setOptions({

        styles: styles
    });
});
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/kofoeppw/)</kbd>

Comment: Hi MrUpsidown, Thanks for reply and I like the way you are doing this but I just noticed an issue here which I didn't mentioned it before( Sorry! my Bad!). The point is this solution works perfectly IF we have ONLY one checkbox for on or off of Roads, but what if we have multi options for let's say Streets, Administrative and even Water. How can turn all style on or off if one not selected or some selected? Thanks