# Stacking Map Styles (Google Maps API)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So I can't find an answer to this, but I know it's possible, because I've seen it.

I'm trying to toggle specific style options on my custom styled map without having to reinitialize the map and losing any pins dropped, or locations searched.

For example, turning off and on road labels. I have accomplished this in a hacky way where I've created two complete style objects, and I switch between them with `map.setMapTypeId`.

The problem with this is that a) it's very repetitive, and b) I have a lot of options I want to be able to toggle, so having to make styled sheets for every single variation of my toggle-able options is not realistic.

The realistic solution is to be able to concat objects on to my style options without undoing the previous style options entirely.

e.g.

```
  {
    'featureType': 'landscape',
    'elementType': 'geometry',
    'stylers': [{'color': '#eaeaea'}]
  }
```

then concatenating this style:

```
  {
    'featureType': 'all',
    'elementType': 'labels',
    'stylers': [{'visibility': 'off'}]
  }
```

I can't just alter the original object because the styles won't take until the map is reloaded, causing me to lose my markers and map position.

I need it to function something like `map.setMapTypeId('styled_map', 'styled_map_2');` where my styles are just compiled.

Hopefully I've made the dilemma clear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [google map set styles dynamically of map object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40658519/google-map-set-styles-dynamically-of-map-object)

Comment: @geocodezip sort of, but not exactly. They seem to be using a similar method to my work around right now where I have separate style objects for every variation of style they want. I didn't know that `setOptions` was a method I could call though, and I may be able to use that to further hack this together and function a little closer to my desired result. Thanks for the direction.

Comment: Styles you pass to the map is just an array of individual styles. You could probably rebuild that array every time you "toggle" something, based on your inputs (checkboxes, buttons or whatever they are) and use `map.setOptions()` which allows to update the styles without reloading anything.

Comment: I had posted an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28081912/looking-for-a-correct-way-to-hide-or-display-streets-on-map

Comment: @MrUpsidown that's what I ended up doing. Altered my options objects based on checkbox booleans and then ran setOptions to refresh only the map styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// create a variable for the element you want an option for
var styleOptionCityLabels = {
  featureType: 'administrative',
  elementType: 'labels',
  stylers: [{'visibility': 'on'}]
};

// create a variable for your map styles that pulls any option variables you have
var mapStyle = [styleOptionCityLabels];

  // get the checkbox element you want to control your toggle
  var cityCheck = $('#city-labels-checkbox');

  // apply a click listener to the box
  cityCheck.on('click', function(){

    // check if the box is checked
    if ($(cityCheck).is(':checked')) {

     // change the desired style
     styleOptionCityLabels.stylers = [{'visibility': 'on'}];
    } else {

     // change the desired style
     styleOptionCityLabels.stylers = [{'visibility': 'off'}];
    }

    // call the setOptions method to reload the altered styles
    map.setOptions({styles: mapStyle}); 
  });
```

Comment: That is similar, yes, except that this will work only for 1 control while my solution will work with any number of controls.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing that would be as explained in this post [Looking For a Correct Way to Hide or Display Streets on Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28081912/looking-for-a-correct-way-to-hide-or-display-streets-on-map)

This is if you just need to toggle the visibility of elements on and off.

If you need more flexibility than that, based on the same idea as the above and what I mentioned in my first comment, you can have more flexibility. Here is a quick POC using checkboxes and data attributes to change stuff around.

```js
var map;

function initialize() {

  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(46.2, 6.17);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

  $('input').change(changeStyles);

  changeStyles();
}

function changeStyles() {

  // Empty styles array
  var styles = [];

  // Loop through all checkboxes
  $('input:checkbox').each(function(i, el) {

    // If the checkbox is checked, we use it
    if ($(el).prop('checked')) {

      // Create the style object
      var style = {
        "featureType": $(el).data('feature-type'),
        "elementType": $(el).data('element-type'),
        "stylers": []
      };

      // Split the data-stylers value to get our stylers object key and value
      var values = $(el).data('stylers').split(':');
      var ob = {};

      // Use our data key and value
      ob[values[0]] = values[1];

      // Push the styler
      style.stylers.push(ob);

      // Push the style
      styles.push(style);
    }
  });

  // Set the map style
  map.setOptions({
    styles: styles
  });
}

initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<input type="checkbox" data-feature-type="water" data-element-type="geometry.fill" data-stylers="color:#1cb9ff"> Change Water Color
<input type="checkbox" checked data-feature-type="all" data-element-type="labels.text" data-stylers="visibility:off"> Hide labels

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Code is commented so it should be easy to understand the concept. Obviously you would need to extend it a bit if you require to change more than one option with one checkbox.

Comment: I essentially did something very similar, but a little different approach. I'll post my solution below.

Comment: The least you could do would be to upvote answers that apparently helped you achieve what you were after. That's how it works here.